# ¿Es correcto "pegarle a un padre"? Y en general, ¿se puede repetir el complemento indirecto en una frase usando "le" o "se" además del explícito?

Tags: gramática, objetos-indirectos

A veces se dice en tono jocoso:

> Es más malo que **pegarle** a un padre.
>
> Es más feo que **pegarle** a un padre.

Para designar algo que es extremadamente malo o feo. Lo que me produce curiosidad es que se utilice *pegarle* y no *pegar* (sondeo rápido googleando cada opción). Yo creo que lo correcto es:

> Es más feo que **pegar** a un padre.

Si mi gramática no está más oxidada de lo que pienso, el *le* aquí ejerce de objeto indirecto, pero este ya está explicitado diciendo *a un padre*.

Entonces, ¿contempla en general la gramática como correcta la reiteración del complemento indirecto en las oraciones? ¿O directamente podemos afirmar que lo único correcto es decir *es más feo que pegar a un padre*?

Comment: La coaparición del complemento indirecto (casi) siempre es posible, solo es obligatorio cuando el complemento es pronombre personal (*a nosotros*, *a él*, etc). Lo que me extraña (como extranjero) es que pegar toma el indirecto en este caso y no directo (pegarlo). Al principio pensaba que era un leísmo pero no, encontré ejemplos de diversos países no leístas con *le* cuando sustituí *mujer*.

Comment: Es lo mismo que preguntar si es correcto decir "le estoy escribiendo una carta a mi padre". La cuestión se podría formular de forma más genérica preguntando si se puede repetir el complemento indirecto en una frase usando "le" o "se" además del explícito.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the role of the "le" in the sentence "Miguel le dio a su novia un anillo."?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2104/what-is-the-role-of-the-le-in-the-sentence-miguel-le-dio-a-su-novia-un-anillo)

Comment: @guifa El CD de pegar es el tipo de golpe: v. la entrada del DLE para [pegar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SKdzxQw), acepción 6: _pegar un bofetón, un tiro_

Comment: En Chile el "_le_" superfluo es casi obligatorio. No vas a oir a nadie decir "_más feo que pegar al padre_". Por cierto, lo frecuente acá es: _más feo que pegarle a la mamá_.

Comment: @rsanchez ciertamente son parecidas, pero a mi entender no duplicadas: la pregunta que mencionas consulta qué categoría gramatical tiene _le_ en una frase dada, mientras que yo pregunto si es correcto usarlo. Dicho lo cual, las respuestas a la otra pregunta abarcan ambos contenidos, por lo que no veo descabellado generalizar la otra y marcarlas como duplicadas. ¡Gracias!

Comment: @CarlosAlejo tienes razón, lo que pasa es que me hizo gracia plantearlo en esta forma concreta, por el título que queda (_¿es correcto pegarle a un padre?_). Como siempre, está más que recomendado usar [edit] para mejorar las preguntas y, después de la broma inicial, creo que es pertinente, pero yo ahora no tengo tiempo

Comment: No, si el título está genial, de hecho yo he caído a veces en la redacción de títulos jocosos. Pensaba más bien en que una vez puesto el ejemplo se puede pasar a un contexto más amplio.

Comment: @Rodrigo en todo el mundo hispanohablante la duplicación del C.I. es mucho más frecuente en el lenguaje oral que en el escrito, por eso probablemente fedorqui ha tenido la duda (ya que solemos pensar que lo oral no es tan correcto como lo escrito)

Comment: solo quería decir que me ha hecho gracia la primera parte del titulo de la pregunta si omitimos las comillas "¿es correcto pegarle a un padre?".

Comment: @BrianH. jejeje nunca dejes pasar la ocasión de captar la atención con un buen título :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ambas formas son correctas.

Dice el *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas*

> **[Pronombres personales átonos](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?id=elLl31yYnD65MTS9uF)**
>   5. [...] La duplicación del complemento indirecto a través del pronombre átono es siempre posible y, en algunos casos, obligatoria, [...]

Sería obligatorio en nuestro caso si dijésemos *pegarle a él* (siendo *él* el padre) o si pusiésemos el complemento antes del verbo, *que al padre pegarle*, en una situación no contrastiva.

Answer (score 3):

En la *Nueva Gramática* se puede leer en el capítulo 35 dedicado al [complemento indirecto](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wMsUDqZrzQzDgmsl):

> [...] el grupo preposicional [encabezado por la preposición *a*] aparece en oraciones en las que, o bien puede ser reemplazado por un pronombre átono de dativo, o bien puede concurrir con él. [...]
>
> La segunda [opción], en la que concurren el pronombre dativo y el grupo preposicional, ilustra las llamadas construcciones de doblado (o de duplicación) del pronombre átono [...].

En el [apartado 35.4](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=puIKkZDRpHPgBaYO) se profundiza en este aspecto con más detalle, indicando que esta concurrencia puede ser opcional en algunos casos, mientras que en otras se hacen imprescindibles. El caso es que en ningún momento dice que dicha concurrencia sea incorrecta, por lo que la respuesta a tu pregunta es que ambas son correctas.

Answer (score 1):

Parte de la confusión es por traducir pegar como golpear cuando pegar tiene dos acepciones, una que viene del latín *picare* (pegar con pez) y otra del *picare* propio del latín vulgar tardío derivado de *picus* (pájaro carpintero). Por eso necesita el *le*, para indicar qué variante es.

Answer (score 0):

Ambas formas son correctas. La razón de usar *le* es para evitar la confusión con la acepción de **unir** o **acercar**.

En el ejemplo, se pretende usar la acepción de **golpear**. Entonces, si en un principio hubiésemos elegido tal verbo, no sería necesario usar *le*:

> Es más feo que **golpear** a un padre