# Determining the indirect object and why 'le' is used in "prefiero que no le digas nada a nadie"

Tags: gramática, verbos, objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos

I am trying to learn and include direct and indirect object pronouns. The line below I don't understand why there is a *le* in the sentence at all. I don't think (and guessing incorrectly) there is an indirect object

> yo prefiero que no le digas nada a nadie.

Its possible I have the translation wrong,

> I prefer that you don't say anything to anyone

I am also not sure what is the direct object in this sentence. The *prefiero* and *digas* are confusing me.

Comment: What do you think the roles of "nada" and "nadie" are? Or rather, why do the think they *aren't* the direct and indirect objects?

Comment: ah! So as digas is acting on nada, nada is the direct object? And since nadie is the recipient of nada it is the indirect object? Is that correct? Can I ask if the direct object of prefiero is the rest of the sentence beyond que?

Comment: Your translation is spot on. You could also say, "I prefer that you not say anything to anyone." // The direct object is "nada," and the indirect object is "nadie" and "le."  To understand this redundancy, take a look at https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20199/9385 and https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2104/9385

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pronoun *le* (singular indirect object pronoun) has the same referent as *nadie* (which is preceded by the preposition *a* because that's how you mark an indirect object). There's a rule that says that in this kind of sentence the indirect object must be present as an unstressed pronoun, even if it's already there in full form (as a stressed pronoun or a noun phrase preceded by *a*).

The direct object is *nada*, as you can see if you try removing the indirect one (*prefiero que no digas nada* = "I'd rather you said nothing"). As with English *say*, Spanish *decir* can act as a transitive or a ditransitive verb.

Note that you can also leave the indirect object implicit if the context is clear, which you can't do with English *say* (the meaning then changes to that of *tell*):

> *Prefiero que no le digas a nadie.* = "I'd rather you didn't tell anyone."

Comment: Thanks @pablodf76! You said that "There's a rule". Is there an easy way to explain this rule?

Comment: It's sort of a rule. If the full IO, the unstressed IO pronoun *has* to appear too when the IO precedes the verb (*"A Pedro no le digas"*) and/or when it's a stressed pronoun (*"No le digas a él"*). But according to what I just checked, if the pronoun is *nadie, ninguno, alguien, alguno*, etc. (these are called indefinite pronouns), then the duplication of the IO pronoun is optional. In every case, though, it's much more common to use the unstressed IO pronoun than not; dropping it can be heard as formal.

Comment: Thanks! So I could maybe say "No digas a nadie" instead of "no le digas a nadie" but it would be weird and formal?

Comment: Yes. *"No digas a nadie"* is really weird, less so (for some reason) *"No digas nada a nadie"*.