# Why does Spanish use object reduplication as in "les pasan a personajes"?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, pronombres

I have a hard time understanding why does Spanish duplicate the indirect objects in its sentences:

> les pasan a los personajes

- Is there a *name* for this phenomenon that is specific to Spanish (and apparently to some Balkan langauges?)
- Can someone explain when are we obliged to duplicate the object with its pronoun (I mean is it only with indirect animate objects, or is it also with direct, etc., etc.)
- Is it a region-specific usage or does is it governed by precise grammatical rules?
- (bonus question), do you know any other language that has similar or equal usage?

Comment: to emphasize the indirect object, we do it as well with direct objects or subjects of the sentence. I don't think there is a proper rule rather than want to empasize on something. It is not region specific, but I would say culture specific, I feel that spanish people do it more often than southamericans, we are more direct when talking. Have a look at French or any Latin language.

Comment: We have discussed this recently: see [this answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32251/24236), and also [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2104/24236), which in my opinion is less clear. I am voting to close this question as a duplicate, but feel free to let us know if the proposed duplicates do not answer your question.

Comment: @Charo exactly, that is why I keep shamelessly self-promoting [my answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32251/24236) to [the other question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32243/24236). The answers to the question you link contradict each other, and are either not correct or do not answer the question "when is it obligatory to reduplicate the IO?".

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [this one](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2104), but the accepted answer of that question is not correct (if it were correct, you couldn't say, for instance, "He escrito un e-mail a Juan" without any dative pronoun). I've just written my own [anwser](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32926) based, as you can see, on the contents of the books *Enciclopedia de lingüística hispánica* and *Gramática descriptiva de la lengua española*.

Comment: Answer to your bonus question: Catalan ("Això li ha passat a en Joan", not  "Això ha passat a en Joan"), but to a lower extent that Spanish.